# How to stop Pytest from executing the non test python file?

Tags: python-3.x, pytest

I have written a Python script that connects to a SQLite3 database and creates a table. I've created another python file to perform some testing using Pytest. For some reason, whenever I run the test file, the code in the main file seems to get executed too and a table is created. I assume Pytest will only execute python files with the word `test` in the beginning or the end of the file name. Not sure what's happening here.

My `py1.py` file

```
import sqlite3


# Create sqlite3 table
def create_table(table_name):
    try:
        print('Creating table in db')
        conn = sqlite3.connect('lite.db')
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + table_name + " (Id INTEGER)")
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()
        print('Table successfully created')
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

db_table_name = 'my_temp_table'

create_table(db_table_name)
```

If I run this file, an empty table called `my_temp_table` is created as expected.

Now I dropped the `my_temp_table` table and tried running the below `test_py1.py` file using Pytest:

```
from py1 import create_table

def test_function():
    assert true
```

The expected behaviour is for it to say 1 test passed, which it does, but along with that it's also creating a table called `my_temp_table`, which indicates the `py1.py` is also being run by Pytest. I'm not sure what is triggering this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding this at the end of your `py1.py` file should solve the problem.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    db_table_name = 'my_temp_table'
    create_table(db_table_name)
```